# AJAX converts cyrillic to some encoding

Tags: php, ajax, encoding

I have a problem. After submission of a form I send request using AJAX. Everything was perfect until I tried Cyrillic text.

what I input: `питання`

what alerts me javascript: `питання`

what echos me $_POST['question']: `%u041F%u0438%u0442%u0430%u043D%u043D%u044F`

Here's my AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addQuestion.php",
        data: "u_id=" + $("#u_id").val() + "&u_a_name=" + $("#u_a_name").val() + "&question="+escape($("#question_input").val()),
        success: function(data) {
                if (data == "Asked") {
                alert("Asked");
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    });
```

So I thought it is AJAX problem, but I haven't found answer in internet.
Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript's `escape()` doesn't work too well with non-ASCII characters, and to handle any unicode characters I generally use `encodeURIComponent()` instead.  In PHP, you can use `urldecode()` to reverse the same encoding.  So:

Javascript: `encodeURIComponent("питання")` returns `%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F`

PHP: `urldecode("%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F");` returns `питання`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 1):

`escape` uses non-standard URL encoding and shouldn't be used at all.

Anyway, with jQuery, you wouldn't put your data as string but as an object and let jQuery format and encode it:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addQuestion.php",
        data: {
            u_id: $("#u_id").val(),
            u_a_name: $("#u_a_name").val(),
            question: $("#question_input").val()

        },

        success: function(data) {
                if (data == "Asked") {
                alert("Asked");
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
});
```

Much cleaner and easier.